# Editable webform fields in views

Tags: views, webforms

I'm using drupal 7.41 and have used [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) for my leave applicaiton form and there are such approvals fields that I've displayed in [views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views), I'd like to make it editable in [views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) by checking multiple records and it can be approved on views list page, can anybody please suggest some hints?

Answer (score 1):

```
function hook_views_post_execute(&$view) {
  // If there are more than 100 results, show a message that encourages the user
  // to change the filter settings.
  // (This action could be performed later in the execution process, but not
  // earlier.)
  if ($view->total_rows > 100) {
    drupal_set_message(t('You have more than 100 hits. Use the filter settings to narrow down your list.'));
  }
}
```

Comment: you can use this function

Comment: also   check  function hook_views_pre_render

Comment: but how may I update webform submission like [Editable Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/editableviews) ?